# How to ignore bottomNavigationBar with the Align widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Say there is a `Scaffold` with a `bottomNavigationBar` property that is populated. If you use a `Stack` with a `Align` widget inside its body set to `Alignment.center`, the `Align` widget gets centered accounting to the `bottomNavigationBar` and centers in the remaining space minus that.

How do I get it so that it centers according to the total screen height, using all these widgets?

```
Stack(
    body: Align widget with center alignment and some child,
    bottomNavigationBar: Bottom app bar
)
```

Comment: Can you please show a simple visual representation for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean in your question - but I think you want the body of a Scaffold (not Stack) to center a widget for the whole height available on the device.

Here's how you could do that using a Scaffold, SizedBox and Center widgets along with a MediaQuery

```
Scaffold(
    body: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Center(
            child: Text("CENTERED")),
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(items: []),
)
```

[Scaffold](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html)

[Sized Box](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html)

[Center](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html)

[Media Query](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html)

Hopefully that puts you on the right path.